# Sending file and form data together in multipart/form-data

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I've spent hours on what seems like it should be a simple task with python requests. I can send files separately from form data, but I can't figure out how to send files together *with* form data.

Here is the structure of what I'm trying to send. Ultimately I need to be able to send an array of files, but right now I'd be grateful if I could just get the request to send at all:

```
buffer = open('./awesome.doc', 'rb')
files = ('awesome.doc', buffer, 'application/msword')

data = {}
data['body_format'] = 'html'
data['created_at'] = 1457722237.0
data['type'] = 'email'
data['subject'] = 'Communications'
data['to'] = ["asdf@asdf.com"]
data['metadata'] = {
    "is_archived": False,
    "is_inbound": False,
    "should_skip_rules": True
}
data['attachments'] = files
```

I've tried any number of things to get this to send, including using `requests_toolbelt`, but I haven't had success with any of them - it's supposed to be possible to send this type of request with `python-requests`, so I'd like to stick to something simple if possible.

This is what I've currently been trying:

```
def url(endpoint): return API_URL % (endpoint)
endpoint = '/inboxes/2341234/imported_messages'

kwargs = {
    'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % TOKEN,
    },
}

requests.post(url(endpoint), data=json.dumps(data), files=buffer)
# ValueError: Data must be a string

requests.post(url(endpoint), data=data, files=buffer)
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Is it just not possible to do what I'm trying to do?